# How to manually turn on Android xml auto complete

Tags: android

While working on my Android xml file(content below), for a TransitionDrawable, I noticed when I typed android:, I didn't get a drop down list of auto-completed options of possible attributes like usual. Is there a manual way to turn on this auto-complete feature for one of your Android xml files?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cyan_shape"
        android:right="125dp"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/magenta_shape"
          android:left="125dp"/>
</transition>
```

Comment: rest of code showing intellisense (drop down)?

Comment: For some of xmls specially those are under drawable eclipse doesn't provide drop down

Comment: Amy, other files do. When I copied the contents of this one, eclipse stopped providing drop down as well. Must be what RIT said

Comment: did you checked it by restarting eclipse or adb server... in some cases this solves the problem

Comment: adb server? doesnt that have to do with emulators?